# Django doesn't look for static files in my app

Tags: django, django-staticfiles

I've developed a stand-alone Django app that has one static JS file. On *some* installations, Django development server can't find the static file. The app is installed as a Python Package with pip, and I can find the JS file in `site-packages/appname/static/js/myfile.js`

I've installed the Django Debug Toolbar, and when looking at the "static" panel, I see a list of "static file apps". My app is not listed there. How can I tell Django it should look at my app's static file folder, too?

I'm using Django 1.6.3, with the following static file finders:

```
STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
)
```

The `django.contrib.staticfiles` app is installed.

Update: When using `manage.py collectstatic`, files from the app are not copied.

Comment: Have you ran collectstatic?

Comment: I'm using the development web-server.

Comment: Ah, just saw that. What are your STATIC_ROOT, STATIC_URL, and STATICFILES_STORAGE settings?  I'm assuming your app is listed in INSTALLED_APPS..?

Comment: Yes, it is. But it did help me solve the problem.

Comment: Do share with the class ;-)

Comment: Check out the answer. It was stupid. I wonder if I can change git's behavior so it doesn't happen again.

Answer (score 1):

OK, this was stupid.

The app in question was previously part of the old project. I've changed it into an independent app on a *different* development machine. When I wrapped it as an independent app I deleted the `myproject/myapp` folder on the other machine, and used `pip install` to install it to the project's virtual env.

Then I used this development machine, did a `git pull` and `pip install`. Turns out this *doesn't delete the `myproject/myapp` folder - it just deletes all the files handled by git. `.pyc` files are not deleted, so the folder remained, and Django looked for static files in that folder, instead of the one in `site-packages`.

Removing `myproject/myapp` fixed this.